# How to solve this combinatorial problem of choosing coloured shirts

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Jack, John and Joe are triplets. Jack has shirts in red, blue, green and white. John's are red, green, white and purple. Joe's are red, blue, white and purple. Each boy has only one shirt of each color and will pick one to wear at random. How many different color combinations are possible? (Order doesn't matter)

I tried to solved it using stars and bars approach as the solution of a multiset consisting of 5 distinct objects in 3 indistinguishable boxes. But that doesn't seem to be giving the correct answer. I don't understand any other approach towards this problem.

Comment: Added my approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by means of stars and bars with an extra condition.

To be found is the number of quintuples $(R,B,G,W,P)\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$ that satisfy: $$R+B+G+W+P=3$$under the extra condition that $B,G,P\leq2$

If we neglect the extra condition then we find $\binom{3+5-1}{5-1}=35$ possibilities.

Then observe that only in $3$ cases the extra condition is not satisfied which are: $$(0,3,0,0,0),(0,0,3,0,0),(0,0,0,0,3)$$

So the answer is: $$35-3=32$$

Comment: How do I understand what to take as objects and boxes in this problem? The shirts are distinguishable and the boys are indistinguishable. So the shirts will serve as the boxes? Also if the order mattered will there be 5 boxes or 4?

Comment: I am not thinking in terms of boxes and objects. E.g. $R$ stands for the number of red shirts in total worn by the boys. It can take value $0,1,2,3$. Since there are $3$ boys we must have $R+B+G+W+P=3$. E.g. the extra condition $B\leq2$ is a consequence of the fact that in total there are only $2$ blue shirts.